# regularization and punishment method in least square fitting

Tags: least-squares, bessel-functions, regularization

I have a least square problem:
$$
\min \sum_j^p| f(x_j)-y_j |^2 \\
\text{where } f(x) = a x - \sum_{i}^{n} b_i J_1(c_i x)
$$
where $J_1$ is the first order Bessel function. I have to find a set consists of $(2n+1)$ parameters $\{ a, b_1, ... b_n, c_1, ..., c_n \}$ that minimize the residual function.

Because the Bessel function oscillates all the time, it seems there are many possible ways to fit. And in most cases, the fitting curve also oscillates rapidly (see fig below), which looks like over-fitting.
[image: the over-fitting case]

I have used the L2 regularization method, but the regularization parameters determined by GCV method cannot work well (either too big that the fitting curve becomes a horizontal straight line, or too small that the curve still over-fitting). Is there some other ways to determined the regularization parameter?

Moreover, if I want to let the adjacent $b_i$ have the same sign, is there a possible way to add a punishment term? And how to determine the punishment strength?

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you applied L2 regularization only to the $c_i$ coefficients. If they are small then each term in the sum will vary more slowly.

Comment: Thanks! I will test this later. BTW,  due to the physical significance of the problem, I would like to see that adjacent $b_i$ and $b_{i+1}$ positive and negative signs do not change particularly drastically, i.e. I don't want something like [1 - 1 1 - 1 - 1 1], but something like [3 2 1 1 0 - 1 -2 - 1 - 1] would be an acceptable change in sign. For this reason I wonder if I need to add some form of regular term to the minimization function, do you know how to do this? Do you know how to do this? Or do you have any other insights into limiting the sign change of $b_i$?